# CSS Override Being Ignored

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am attempting to invalidate the default Site.css rule that `body` has a     `padding-top: 50px;`.  My goal is to reduce the whitespace between the Bootstrap 3 navbar and the start of the body content.  This doesn't seem to be a property of the navbar that is doing this, it seems to be the default padding on the `body`.

This is in MVC, so I modified my _Layout.cshtml to include it's own `<style>` section and added the following to the `head` section:

```
.body {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
}
```

When I view this in the Chrome developer's console, the body element is still taking on the properties from Site.css:

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

My HTML source does show my overrides in the `head`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm guessing they have equal priority and it doesn't know which to apply. Try making a more specific CSS selector by adding a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining the body as a class with the dot, try and remove it, that might be why it dosen't override

Answer (score 0):

```js
.body {
    padding-top: inherit;
}
```